# How to pass changed data back to Fragment's list?

Tags: android

I have a `ListFragment` with arbitrary data. When I tap on an item, it's data passes through `Bundle` to another `EditFragment`, where I retrieve it and store in `EditText` for editing. How do I pass edited data back and apply changes for the selected item in arraylist? Same way through `Bundle`? Am I supposed to access ListFragment's listview at the same time?

EditFragment:

```
public class EditFragment extends Fragment {

    MenuItem save;
    MenuItem cancel;
    View view;
    EditText editText;
    int position;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_fragment_layout, container, false);
        editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Bundle b = getArguments();

        position = b.getInt("position");

        editText.setText(b.getString("name"));
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.edit_fragment, menu);

        save = menu.findItem(R.id.save);
        cancel = menu.findItem(R.id.cancel);

        cancel.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                MyListFragment myListFragment = (MyListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyListFragment");

                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragContainer, myListFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

                return true;
            }
        });

        save.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                MyListFragment myListFragment = (MyListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyListFragment");
                //here we need to save changed data in our arraylist
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("position", position);
                bundle.putString("name", editText.getText().toString());
                myListFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                //should I get my bundle data here?
                Bundle b = getArguments();

                //ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter) myListFragment.getListView().getAdapter();

                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragContainer, myListFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can put the data in the Bundle. Another approach is to have an ArrayList as the model so when the edit text changes the value you change your model. If you are starting with Android Programming. Here is a great book to get you started. https://www.bignerdranch.com/we-write/android-programming/

Comment: You might want to consider having the Activity manage the communication between the fragments: http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: @LeoLandau, I'm using Activity to manage communication by means of Communicator interface, but still cannot figure out on how to pass data back

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi, thanks for book, will try to find info about Fragments there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon creation of EditFragment set your invoking ListFragment as EditFragment's target by calling myEditFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);.

In your EditFragment, get that fragment object with getTargetFragment() and call onActivityResult method of fragment.

In list fragment override onActivityResult and get bundle from intent to get data.

Hope it helps.